# Is there a JRuby-Rack Sinatra Warbler Project archtype?

Tags: ruby, jruby, sinatra, jruby-rack

Is there a project archetype (or whatever the ruby community calls it) for a jruby + rack + Sinatra project that creates a WAR deployment file with all required dependencies all ready to go?

What I want is the equivalent to "rails appname" that creates a ready to go project with ant/rake scripts and a basic directory hierarchy all ready to go.

Does such a beast exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby-rack/pages/Home#For_Other_Rack_Applications) which shows how rack can be used with sinatra